# Common zeros of two univariate polynomials over $\mathbb{C}(y)$

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra, substitution, resultant

Let $f=f(x), g=g(x) \in \mathbb{C}[y][x] \subset \mathbb{C}(y)[x]$, where $\{x,y\}$ are variables over $\mathbb{C}$, and each of $\{f,g\}$ is of $x$-degree $\geq 1$, namely, $f$ and $g$ are non-constant polynomials over $\mathbb{C}(y)$ in one variable $x$.

Write $f=a_nx^n+\cdots+a_1x+a_0$, $g=b_mx^m+\cdots+b_1x+b_0$, where $a_i=a_i(y),b_j=b_j(y) \in \mathbb{C}[y]$, $1 \leq i \leq n, 1 \leq j \leq m$.

Fix $c \in \mathbb{C}$, and denote $\tilde{a_i}:=a_i(c)$ and $\tilde{b_j}:=b_j(c)$,
$\tilde{f}:=\tilde{a_n}x^n+\cdots+\tilde{a_1}x+\tilde{a_0}$ and 
$\tilde{g}=\tilde{b_m}x^m+\cdots+\tilde{b_1}x+\tilde{b_0}$,
$1 \leq i \leq n, 1 \leq j \leq m$.

(Clearly, $\tilde{a_i},\tilde{b_j} \in \mathbb{C}$ so $\tilde{f},\tilde{g} \in \mathbb{C}[x]$).

Assume that $f$ and $g$ do not have a common zero in $\mathbb{C}(y)$ (= their resultant is non-zero).

> Is it true that $\tilde{f}$ and $\tilde{g}$ do not have a common zero in $\mathbb{C}$?

**Remarks:** **(1)** Of course, if $f$ and $g$ do not have a common zero in $\mathbb{C}(y)$, then (in particular) $f$ and $g$ do not have a common zero in $\mathbb{C}$, but here I am asking about $\tilde{f}$ and $\tilde{g}$, not $f$ and $g$.

**(2)** Perhaps my question in trivial and has a positive answer? I only know that if $\tilde{f}$ and $\tilde{g}$ have a common zero $d \in \mathbb{C}$, then $f=f(x,y)|(x=d,y=c)=\tilde{f}(d)=0$ and $g=g(x,y)|(x=d,y=c)=\tilde{g}(d)=0$, but I do not see if this should imply that $f$ and $g$ have a common zero in $\mathbb{C}(y)$. (Perhaps a universal property is relevant here).

Any comments and hints are welcome!

Comment: Hmm, am I misunderstanding this?  It seems trivially false.  Take $f = x - y, g = x - y^2$, $c=0$.  Then $f,g$ have no common roots in $\mathbb{C}(y)$, since the unique roots are $y$ and $y^2$, but $\tilde{f} = \tilde{g} = x$.

Comment: Thank you! It seems that you are right.. What about the converse implication? (true?)

Comment: $\tilde{f}$ and $\tilde{g}$ have a common zero if $c$ is a zero of the resultant of $f$ and $g$.

Comment: For the converse, let $f=g = yx-1$ and $c = 0$.  Then $\tilde{f}, \tilde{g} = -1$ have no roots, but $f,g$ have a common root $1/y$ in $\mathbb{C}(y)$.

Comment: @random, your comment sounds interesting.

Comment: I wonder: is it true that if $f(x,c), g(x,c)$ have a common root for every $c \in \mathbb{C}$ then $f,g$ have a common root in $\mathbb{C}(y)$ or its completion?

Comment: @JairTaylor, nice! What if $f \neq g$ and each is monic ($a_n=b_m=1$)? I guess that again it is possible to find a counterexample..

Comment: Not sure, but you could look at examples where $c$ is a pole of the common root $r(y)$ since otherwise you can just plug $c$ into $r(y)$ to get a root of $\tilde{f}, \tilde{g}$.

Comment: Actually, I believe the converse is true if you assume they are monic.  If $f,g$ are monic and have a common root in $\mathbb{C}(y)$ then they have a common root $p(y) \in \mathbb{C}[y]$ by Gauss' lemma.  Then, $p(c)$ is a common root of $\tilde{f}, \tilde{g}$.